# Merits of using npm over shell program(Bash)

Tags: bash, shell, npm

I have recently started using npm (https://www.npmjs.com) and it's wonderful that we can use npm as build tool. But after digging much, I got question in my mind.

As a building tool, npm is almost like shell program(sh or bash), because we just execute shell commands in npm package.json file. And even sometimes we execute shell program from it.

EDIT: here is an example how I use it.

package.json

{
  "name": "myproject",
  "devDependencies": {
    "jshint": "latest",
    "minify": "latest",
    "mocha": "latest"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "jshint **.js",
    "test": "mocha test/",
    "minify":"minify *.js",
    "build":"npm run lint && npm run test && npm run minify"
  }
}

So, everything we're doing with npm bundling facility, we can achieve by writing normal shell program(sh or bash). I want to know what are special advantages of npm over nprmal shell program. What we can't do with shell script, which we can achieve with npm as build tool.

There must be some special vision behind developing tool. Otherwise everything we can do with shell program (Makefile).

Your answer will be appreciated.

Thanking in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Npm as a build tool: do you mean the [npm scripts feature](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)? Or something like Grunt or Gulp?

Npm itself is just a package ecosystem for JavaScript (Node) packages. Shell is, well, shell. You can create shell programs with anything which can be run using a shell (Bash, C, Python, PHP, and so on). I presume you mean shell languages like *sh* or *bash* in your question.

If you develop Node or browser applications, or use a tool such as Gulp, Grunt, Fly, npm scripts and so on then npm is a good (mandatory) pick.

If you need to create build procedures for something really custom or lower level than regular applications, then custom shell builders or maybe Makefiles could be a better fit. Though some people seem to use Makefiles in places where npm and a build tool like Gulp would be a simpler choice.

What are you building with npm right now which got you questioning the usage of it?

Comment: I would suggest to refer this: http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/           Everything they said nice features in npm, we can achieve using shell languages like sh or bash. Then what is benefit of npm?

Comment: The benefit of npm is cross environment package handling. That way your whole team can just `npm install` and get building. With shell scripts everyone on your team may need to go and download tools manually.

Comment: Okay... So it's all about cross-platform ..... I hope something more awesome be there....! But this time Thank you very much.... (And thanks for -1 whoever did ...!!)